# Error - "Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence[])" because "this.UserName" is null

Tags: java, selenium, page-factory

I am a newbie in Java and Selenium.
Below are my java classes for POM, Driver Utilites and Test Case.

When I run the Test Case as TestNG test, I have :
FAILED: verifyLogin
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence[])" because "this.userName" is null.

Please help me out. Let me know if further info is needed.
Thanks in advance.

**<----------------------------------------POM-------------------------------------------------->**

```
package com.inetBankingV1.pageObjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import com.inetBankingV1.utilities.callBrowserDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class LoginPage {
    
    WebDriver driver;
    
    @FindBy(how=How.LINK_TEXT, using="Log in")
    WebElement logUser;
    
    @FindBy(how=How.NAME, using="username")
    WebElement userName;
    
    @FindBy(how=How.NAME, using="password")
    WebElement passWord;
    
    
    //constructor
    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver=driver;
    }
    
    public  void loginCheck(String uname,String passwd)
    {
        userName.sendKeys(uname);
        passWord.sendKeys(passwd);
        logUser.click();
    }

}
```

**<----------------------------------------Driver------------------------------------------------>**

```
    package com.inetBankingV1.utilities;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class callBrowserDriver {
    
    public WebDriver startApplication(String browser, String baseURL, WebDriver driver)
    
    {
    
    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
            {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./Drivers/geckodriver.exe");
        FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
        firefoxOptions.setCapability("marionette", true);
         driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
         
            }
    
    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
            {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
            }
    
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.navigate().to(baseURL);
    
    return driver;

}
    
}
```

**<--------------------------------------Test Case----------------------------------------------->**

```
    package com.inetBankingV1.testCases;

import com.inetBankingV1.utilities.callBrowserDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.inetBankingV1.pageObjects.LoginPage;

public class TC2_VerifyLogin {

    WebDriver driver;
    callBrowserDriver browserDriver=new callBrowserDriver();

    @Test
    public void verifyLogin()
    {
        
        driver=browserDriver.startApplication("chrome","https://demosite.com/",this.driver);
        LoginPage login=new LoginPage(driver);

    login.loginCheck("admin","Password");   
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your login3DExp() method defined?

Comment: @itronic1990: Sorry the function is loginCheck, its in POM class

Comment: Is there a webelement in your webpage with name = username?

Comment: yes @itronic1990. Also after using initElements (which I missed) issue is not seen. Though I have issue of not locating webelemetn which i should figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved after initialising the webelements of the POM class using initElements:

LoginPage login=PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:-

```
 @FindBy(how=How.ID, using="inline-search-submit")
 WebElement logUser;
    
 @FindBy(how=How.NAME, using="user")
 WebElement userName;
    
 @FindBy(how=How.NAME, using="pass")
 WebElement passWord;
```

Comment: Thank you, but the asked question is resolved after initializing the webelements.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use below line in your constructor
PageFactory.initElements( driver, this);

----------------------------------------------

public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) 
    {
        this.driver=driver;
        PageFactory.initElements( driver, this);
    }

This should solve your problem.
```